Compilation fails when I use 'std:mutex'
#include <mutex>

int main() {
  std::mutex mtx;
  return 0;
}

Why does it give me the error that mutex is not in std when I have included <mutex>?
I was compiling this code in VSCode. The version of gcc is
6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) thread model: win32
Error message:

error: 'mutex' is not a member of 'std'


You probably need to specify -std=c++11 or similar flag to the compiler

std::mutex is C++11, and gcc 6.3 is ancient. Did you ask it to compile as c++11? Whats the complete error message? (i wonder it didnt error for the include)

My advice is to uninstall your very old version of MinGW and use msys2 to provide the current version. If you are using VSCode the official instructions tell you to use msys2.

6.3 defaults to gnu++14.  I suspect you have your VSCode project set to C++98, which does not have mutex.  GCC 6.3 is 8 years old; may want to consider using a more current compiler.
